# Pull values that have only numbers PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Table

Column

```
123d4
12345
21232
32432
G4532
Ffh32
H123f
```

output

```
12345
21232
32432
```

please help this is in PLSQL

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '123d4' from dual union all
  3     select '12345' from dual union all
  4     select '21232' from dual union all
  5     select '32432' from dual union all
  6     select 'G4532' from dual union all
  7     select 'Ffh32' from dual union all
  8     select 'H123f' from dual
  9    )
 10  select col
 11  from test
 12  where regexp_like(col, '^\d+$');

COL
-----
12345
21232
32432

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_LIKE` (see answer from Littlefoot) is probably the go-to solution.  But regular expressions are a little more expensive than other SQL functions (or, historically have been more expensive - I have not retested in recent versions).

If maximum performance is key, using `TRANSLATE` might help:

```
with test (col) as
     (select '123d4' from dual union all
      select '12345' from dual union all
      select '21232' from dual union all
      select '32432' from dual union all
      select 'G4532' from dual union all
      select 'Ffh32' from dual union all
      select 'H123f' from dual
     )
   select col
   from test
   -- Keep values that have only number characters
   where translate(col,'.1234567890','.') is null
```

Because of the way `TRANSLATE` works, this will drop all numerals from the input string.  If that leaves an empty string, that means the input had *only* numerals, so we keep it.